# How to Permanently Enable the event_scheduler in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I wrote this : 
"#event_scheduler=on" under "mysqld" section
 in MySQL Server Instance Configuration File : "my.ini" present in the directory :

ProgramData\MySQl\MySQL Server 5.6

But,when I restarted my Computer and started MySQL it shows "event_scheduler=off" and I have to set it againn by :"SET @@global.event_scheduler=on".

Can I permanently turn the event_scheduler "on".If yes,then what will be the steps.Give in detail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lines starting with # are comments in my.ini. Try removing the # and restart the server

Answer (score 0):

Write just like:

```
event_scheduler = 'on'
```